# How to specify fields for detail records with Acumatica ReturnBehavior

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to use the Acumatica API to return a list of Sales Order and Sales Order Details, while limiting the fields returned.

So far, I have :

```
 SalesOrder filter = new SalesOrder
                    {
                        //Filter the SOs returned
                        OrderType = new AcumaticaOpticsExt.StringValue { Value = salesOrder.Split('/').First() },
                        OrderNbr = new AcumaticaOpticsExt.StringValue { Value = salesOrder.Split('/').Last() },

                        //Specify return behavior
                        ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.OnlySpecified,

                        //Specify the fields to be returned on the SO
                        Hold = new BooleanReturn(),
                        CustomerName = new StringReturn(),
                        SchedShipment = new DateTimeReturn(),
                        QtyAllocatedM = new DecimalReturn(),
                        QtyAllocatedNotCompletedM = new DecimalReturn(),
                        //And from the SO Line Detail                       

                    };
```

It's not clear how I can specify the fields from the Details and I haven't found any multi-level uses in the documentation.

Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that works for me :

```
SalesOrder so = new SalesOrder
{
    ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.OnlySpecified,
    OrderType = new StringSearch { Value = "SO", Condition = StringCondition.Equal },
    OrderNbr = new StringSearch { Value = "001253", Condition = StringCondition.Equal },
    Details = new SalesOrderDetail[]
    {
        new SalesOrderDetail
        {
            ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.OnlySpecified,
            InventoryID = new StringReturn(),
            LineNbr = new IntReturn(),
            UOM = new StringReturn(),
            UnitPrice = new DecimalReturn(),
            Quantity = new DecimalReturn()
        }
    }
};
```

You just have to define the array of detail items, in the first one define the return behavior level that you want and if it applies the field(s) that you want to be returned.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick!

AND I think I see embedded in your example an answer to the next question I was wrestling with, using a stringsearch with anything other than equals!